# How to update DEB packages in 20.04

Tags: updates, deb, 20.04

My question is about updating .deb packages in 20.04. I understand that the Ubuntu software center will not support .deb packages in 20.04.

I like to use Google Chrome, which is only available as a .deb package (or .rpm). What is the best way to install Chrome on 20.04? Should I use dpkg?

And if I use dpkg, how do I make sure Chrome remains up to date? In 18.04 Chrome gets updated via the update manager (I think also via the apt package manager). Will this still happen if I install Chrome on 20.04 via dpkg? Is there any way to have it automatically updated via the update manager or via apt?

Thanks for taking the time to view my question.

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: APT is just a front-end for DPKG and Ubuntu software center is for APT. The availability of updates by APT depends on the repositories configured. In case of Google Chrome, when it is installed, it automatically adds key and repository information. You just need to run `apt update; apt upgrade` or open Software updater. Unless you delete that repository information, you'll have latest Chrome if you keep your system regularly updated.

Comment: Kulfy, your explanation on how Chrome automatically installs repository information is very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use dpkg, I just open the `.deb` file and that's it, but please follow the instructions bellow instead.

For the other questions on how to install it via apt and keep it update I'm glad you ask since that is very important.

Run the following commands:

```bsh
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
```

From now on it will show on the update manager each time there's a new version